# instant messenger client I can run on my local machine with a web interface?

Tags: home-server, instant-messaging

I'd like to run an instant messenger client on my server so I can have access to IM anywhere I go. I used to run bitlbee with CGI:IRC but was wondering if there's an easier/more user friendly option out there?

Comment: What IM network(s) do you need access to?

Comment: AIM and Msn, yahoo and jabber would be nice but not required.

Answer (score 2):

Is [Meebo](http://www.meebo.com) not an option? It's a web-based IM client, and supports MSN, Yahoo, GTalk, Jabber, ICQ, Facebook, MySpace, and more.

Comment: I don't like the idea of a third party having access to my message traffic. I may use it if there's no other option but would like to avoid them.

Comment: Technically, Meebo would be a fourth party.  There's you, the person you talk to on the messaging client, the company that runs the service, and then Meebo.  If you're trying to keep communications out of the eyes of others, you might want to go with setting up your own IRC server or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

[SparkWeb](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/sparkweb/) is a web-based Jabber client.  And although it is jabber only, if you are planning on hosting your client on a server, you could also run the [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) server with [IM gateways](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/gateway/readme.html) to other protocols.

Comment: My understanding is you can only run one aim/msn/yahoo gateway at a time. for example if I wanted to sign onto aim using screenname1 and screenname2 this would be impossible to do with openfire unless I used two jabber names.

Comment: Yes, because OpenFire is actually a Jabber server, its designed to allow for several users to connect to their individual accounts through the gateway, so for each account on each IM service you will need a separate Jabber account.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac [Colloquy](http://colloquy.info/) has a web based GUI that you can use remotely.

Answer (score 0):

If privacy is a huge concern, you could always run [pidgin](http://pidgin.im) with the [off-the-record plugin](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/) installed on your server, then just [vnc](http://www.realvnc.com/) into the server to use instant messaging.  Seems like a PITA, but would be super private and secure, and possibly easier than setting up your own messaging client with a web-facing GUI.